# filling combobox from database

Tags: java, apache-flex, arcgis-server

I'm using flex, Java and sql server for webmapping application and i'm trying to fill my combobox from database, but i just get results like this [Object Object] [Object Object] [Object Object] [Object Object] instead of getting the correct values of the fields, this is the code, i think all is right but it doesn't work !!! can you help be to find what i'm messing !!

so first this is the code of my class, it selects a column (Intitule Chapitre) from database

```
public class RapportDao {

    public Connection conectar(){
        Connection cn = null;
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=mabase;user=sa;password=sa;";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return cn;
    }   
public ArrayList<Rapport> Selection() {


             Connection conn = conectar();  
             ArrayList<Rapport> list = null;

             if (conn!=null){

                 try{
                     Rapport pr = null;
                     String a;
                     list = new ArrayList<Rapport>();
                     String sql = "select IntituleChap from Rapport";
                     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                     while (rs.next())
                     {
                         a=rs.getString("IntituleChap");
                         pr  = new Rapport();
                         pr.setIntituleChap(a);
                         list.add(pr);
                     }

             }
                 catch(SQLException e ) {

                     // System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                     System.out.println("Error = " + e.getMessage());
                    }

             }else
             {

             }
             return list;
    }
}
```

and this is my actionscript code for combobox

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/2008/ags"
           minWidth="1000" minHeight="700" applicationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[

    import spark.components.ComboBox;
    private function getTypeprojetResult(event : ResultEvent):void
                {
                    //Alert.show(""+event.result);
                } 

    protected function application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                RemoteRapportDao.Selection()

                }
    ]]>

    <fx:Declarations>
            <s:RemoteObject id="RemoteRapportDao" 
                            destination="RapportDaoDest"
                            fault="onFault(event)">
                <s:method name="Selection" result="getTypeprojetResult(event);"/>
            </s:RemoteObject>
        </fx:Declarations>

<s:ComboBox id="cmb" x="10" y="13" width="162" labelField="IntituleChap" dataProvider="{RemoteRapportDao.Selection.lastResult}" />
```

RemoteRapportDao : is the id RemoteObject
Selection() : my method on the service

any one could help me ?

Comment: you should assign the dataProvider in function getTypeprojetResult. like this `cmb.dataProvider = event.result`

Comment: i made this : private function getTypeprojetResult(event : ResultEvent):void
   {
    
    cmb.dataProvider = event.result;
   }
but i got this Error :
Implicit Coercion of value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type mx.collections : IList

Comment: what's the content in event.result, seems the type of event.result is not implement IList

Comment: I think the same way as huang.xinghui, so I propose checking the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works, thank you all for your help, i just should use ArrayCollection instead of arraylist.

```
public ArrayCollection Selection() {
             Connection conn = conectar();  
                ArrayCollection list =  new ArrayCollection();

             if (conn!=null){

                 try{
                     Rapport pr = null;
                     String a;
                     list = new ArrayList<Rapport>();
                     String sql = "select IntituleChap from Rapport";
                     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                     while (rs.next())
                     {
                         a=rs.getString("IntituleChap");
                         pr  = new Rapport();
                         pr.setIntituleChap(a);
                         list.add(pr);
                     }

             }
                 catch(SQLException e ) {

                     // System.out.print(e.getMessage());
                     System.out.println("Error = " + e.getMessage());
                    }

             }else
             {

             }
             return list;
    }
```

thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely to having issue with representing the results from the query correctly, and therefore the labelField is not trigered correctly with the combo box object.
I would suggest to create a data model representing the results, which would not only great improve readability of the code, but will help you aswell with such no-go issues.

possible example of a data model ( just for a testing purposes ).

```
    package myTopLevelPackage.myPackage
    {
        public class ComboBoxItemDataModel
        {
            public var intituleChap: String;


            public function ComboBoxItemDataModel( o : Object )
            {
                super();
                this.intituleChap = o[ 'IntituleChap' ];
                trace( JSON.encode( o ) ); 
// use this or other suitable method to see actually how Your object looks like, in order to set the object property correctly in the assignment above.
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that I have switched using capital character for a variable IntituleChap to intituleChap.

Comment: thank you Yordan for answering, but i'm not sure if i understand what you mean by creating a data model, could you please explain more, i'm just new in flex so i make some effort to assimilate that !
by the way i'm facing the same problem with a datagrid even if the code is correct !!

Comment: Hello Saadia, I've added one example of a simple data model. Fill a bindable dataprovider with an instance of it, which is created in the body of your `while (rs.next())` see the results, and check the console about how the data model of the upcoming objects actually looks like. If it does not work again, please post the JSON of the objects which been streamed from the server.